# Microsoft access Update DateDiff

Tags: microsoft-access

Preciso fazer um simples update onde eu atualizo a coluna "DiasPendentes" com o valor da data atual menos a data da coluna "DataAbertura".

```
"UPDATE tblPendencia SET DiasPendentes = (DATEDIFF(day, DATAABERTURA, DATE())) WHERE PendenciaOrigem = 'PM'"
```

Estou executando essa query porém está me retornando o erro "No value given for one or more required parameters".

Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Após alguma ajuda...

UPDATE tblPendencia SET tblPendencia.DiasPendentes = (DATEDIFF('d', tblPendencia.AberturaData, Now())) WHERE tblPendencia.PendenciaOrigem = 'PM'"